# Boot Repair won't finish running because commands won't run

Tags: boot, grub2, 13.10, boot-repair

Boot repair asks me to run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" dpkg --configure -a
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get install -fy
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub* shim-signed linux-signed*
```

I think it's so it can remove grub, then reinstall it.

The first two commands run fine, but on the third one:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  grub-common* grub2-common* ubiquity* ubiquity-frontend-gtk*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 297 not upgraded.
After this operation, 22.5 MB disk space will be freed.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libxv1:amd64': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I am trying to install Ubuntu Studio 13.1 as the main operating system on a 64 bit Sony Vaio SVE series.  It has UEFI but I disabled secure boot. The disk won't install the entire thing because it can't copy a grub file to some target. It says the system won't boot withoout the file. Ok, but I think most or all of Ubuntu installed, so I'm trying to fix the boot process from livecd.  But I can't get boot-repair to go any further because it can't remove grub.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
Input/output error
```

generally means that the hardware (HDD) is failing. 
You probably want to backup your documents onto an external disk (USB or DVDs), then check/fix your HDD. Once your HDD is ok, reinstall your system.